# Playing image sequence as video

Tags: c#, .net

I have animations created in Adobe AfterEffects, exported as Targa sequence with alpha channel. Now I am looking for a way to play those images nicely, without any flickering, lagging etc. Unfortunately I have no idea what is the best approach, so can you give me some suggestions ? My app is windows form c#.

I am using the Targa sequence because it has an alpha channel (and I need its transparent background). There are few video formats with alpha channel but so it seems to me it is easier to use the image sequence (for reasons I will not go into) but I am open to format change if it will do the job. I just need some simple way to play nicely the image sequence at 25fps. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to put a picturebox/Graphics.DrawImage() and a timer?

Comment: `Graphics.DrawImage()` should stack the images, handling the transparency of each image, allowing you to only change the pixels that are opaque.

Comment: Sound good thanks, definitely gonna try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a functional code: https://github.com/NickeManarin/ScreenToGif/blob/master/GifRecorder/Legacy.cs
Seek for "Play Preview".

Do you need to show what in the place of the transparent pixels? The last opaque pixel? Or just a background?

If you don't need to show the last opaque pixels, just use a `PictureBox` and set a timer event to 1000/25.

Else, use `Graphics.DrawImage()`.